# Filtering two ICollectionView from a single ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, icollectionview

I have a problem using two `ICollectionView` instances that have the same `ObservableCollection` as source.

When I filter an `ICollectionView`, it seems that also the other `ICollectionView` is filtered with the same filter. I instantiate the `ICollectionView` with the method `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`.

Is this the expected behaviour? I don't think so, but maybe I'm missing something.

This is the constructor of the ViewModel:

```
ListaVoci = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(RootVM.CollectionVociCE);
```

where `ListaVoci` is an `ICollectionView` and `RootVM.CollectionVociCE` is an `ObservableCollection`.
I have two different user controls that have two different instances of this ViewModel.

This is the constructor of the user control:

```
datacontext.ListaVoci.Filter = FiltraListaVoci;
```

where `FiltraListaVoci` is

```
public bool FiltraListaVoci(object filter)
{
    // I make some filtering
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code to see more of the context?

Comment: You can add that as an answer to your own question and accept it; it may be helpful to a future visitor.

Comment: i added the solution I discovered :)

Comment: i can't answer any post of mine because i'm to noob :) i have to wait 8 hours... I'll add it when i can, in the meantime i added the answer editing my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem :) with CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView() I get the same view instance for both the two ICollectionViews, so that they reference the same object. The right way to instantiate the ICollectionView in this case is this:

```
CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.Source = RootVM.CollectionVociSP;
ListaVoci = cvs.View;
```

So I create a Collectionviewsource object whenever the constructor is called. I hope that this doesn't lead to some strange side effects :) Thank you anyway!